# I enable WebGPU in Chrome DEV, and it still doesn't work

Tags: linux, google-chrome, webgpu

So, I have enabled the #enable-unsafe-webgpu flag and I even get a warning when opening Chrome, that "WebGPU is enabled and stability will suffer". Yet, when trying to access any WebGPU example website, I get an error, stating that my browser doesn't support WebGPU / WebGPU is not enabled. What can I do?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Chrome Version 103.0.5056.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For now on Linux Chrome Dev, you can use WebGPU by launching Chrome via cmd line like this:

```
google-chrome-unstable --enable-unsafe-webgpu --enable-features=Vulkan
```

(Basically you need the extra `--enable-features=Vulkan` on Linux as indicated in the F12 developer console)

Comment: There is no command google-chrome-unstable on my Ubuntu20, so I changed to google-chrome, thanks.

Comment: To install google-chrome-unstable try this:
https://linuxg.net/how-to-install-google-chrome-31-unstable-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-elementary-os/

Comment: That does not work with NVidia drivers under Linux. See my answer in this thread.

Comment: That linuxg link is a casino website now.

Comment: For me, `google-chrome-unstable --enable-unsafe-webgpu --enable-features=Vulkan` is already working. On _Version 122.0.6182.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)_ . See https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb/wiki/Implementation-Status#chromium-chrome-edge-etc

Answer (score 2):

If you find that none of the Linux streams (stable, beta, dev) work with WebGPU:

1. [Download the raw Chromium trunk build for Linux x64](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/?platform=Linux_x64&type=snapshots)
2. Make sure [Unsafe WebGPU Support](https://chrome://flags/#enable-unsafe-webgpu) is `enabled`.
3. Use [WebGPU Samples](https://webgpu.github.io/webgpu-samples/) for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it out but, according to [developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/webgpu/](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/webgpu/#browser-support), experimental can be enabled. From the article:

From :

> Linux experimental support is available by running Chrome with --enable-features=Vulkan

Answer (score 1):

**WebGPU on a HTML-5 canvas is work in progress, no release yet**

For use in a browser (that is: other people too) I'd stick with WEBGL2 for now.. *as a user*, I don't like to install programs that call themselves "unstable" or options that are called "unsafe". In the default version of Chrome the flag set option was removed (?) but Chrome seems to copy the setting of Chrome Canary without notice (?) all that does not indicate trust at this moment.. which is reenforced when I open the Webkit page https://webkit.org/demos/webgpu/ and see warnings all over the place.

**You can test WebGPU without the need for a browser**

I'm certainly going to use WebGPU when it comes out. If you want a "sneak preview" there are RUST/Wasm and CPP/Wasm solutions without the need for a browser to render it, I tried https://github.com/cwoffenden/hello-webgpu

Answer (score 1):

To whom it might concern, to have WebGPU enabled by default in Chrome/ium Dev (unstable) channel you can explicitly switch on these flags in `about:flags` or `chrome://flags/` and stuff *should* work out of the box once relaunched ... or at least it does in my Laptop and Desktop machines, powered by AMD for both CPU and GPU.

P.S. it's very possible the Skia flag is not necessary, I just followed the most up-voted answer to date which was mentioning it.

[image: about flags with entries for WebGPU: Vulkan, Skia, unsafe WebGPU]

Comment: what does `pdf-use-skia-renderer` have to do with webgpu?